# equivalence of n-connected spectra

Tags: homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy-theory

Is the following claim true in general?

Claim: A map $f:(X^r)\rightarrow (Y^r)$ of $n$-connective spectra (of simplicial sets) is a stable equivalence if and only if the corresponding map $f:X^n\rightarrow Y^n$ is a weak equivalence.

The original claim is for $n=1$, although I don't know why. Any explanation will be appreciated.